# Sql – Insert value in first empty cell of column and show ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I have an sql statement that will insert a value to the first empty cell. And if I ran the php script again, then it inserts into the next null cell etc.

Problem: I also want to find out the ID of that row, and value of another column in that row. In the Mysql table below, I want a value inserted in the first ‘null’ of COLUMN A, and also know the id and value in COLUMN B corresponding to that (ie id=3 and COLUMN B= 11).

My_TABLE

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| ID      | COLUMN A     |  COLUMN B   |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 1       | 6            | 78          |
| 2       | 7            | 90          |
| 3       |  NULL        | 11          |
| 4       |  NULL        |  5          |
| 5       |  NULL        | 123         |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

The following sql statement in PHP script will make it possible to insert value to the first empty cell in COLUMN A:

```
UPDATE My_TABLE  
SET COLUMN A = 83  
WHERE COLUMN A IS NULL  
LIMIT 1;
```

Result will be:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | COLUMN A | COLUMN B   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 6        |       78   |
|  2 | 7        |       90   |
|  3 | 83       |       11   |
|  4 | NULL     |        5   |
|  5 | NULL     |      123   |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I also want to have an sql script that will print within PHP (echo) the values of ID and COLUMN B values corresponding to the first COLUMN A null value (ie ID= 3; COLUMN B= 11).

Comment: "*the first empty cell in COLUMN A*" makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. fetch the row by condition in this case you will have `ID` and `COLUMN B`

   select *
   from My_TABLE
   where `COLUMN A` IS NULL
   order by id
   limit 1
2. Update by `ID` the selected row:

   update My_TABLE
     set `COLUMN A` = :SOME_VALUE
     where ID = :ID_FROM_FETCH

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this case will fit what you are questioning.

> [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

From this function I'm pretty sure you will able to write the script for what you need.

> **Note*** If it fits what you need, please read the warning as I'm not
> sure if it will deprecated from the latest PHP version. Kindly take
> note.